# How could I create a date picker in groovy?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, datepicker

I see this code for create input field in groovy.

I'm trying to find a example for create a date picker in groovy, but I don't see anything.

How could I create a date picker in groovy?

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
import java.awt.*

@Bindable
class Address { 
    String street, number, city
    String toString() { "address[street=$street,number=$number,city=$city]" }
}

def address = new Address(street: 'Evergreen Terrace', number: '742', city: 'Springfield')

def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
swingBuilder.edt {  // edt method makes sure UI is build on Event Dispatch Thread.
    lookAndFeel 'nimbus'  // Simple change in look and feel.
    frame(title: 'Address', size: [350, 230],
            show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
            defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        borderLayout(vgap: 5)

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,
                border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Enter your address:')])) {
            tableLayout {
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'Street:'  // text property is default, so it is implicit.
                    }
                    td {
                        textField address.street, id: 'streetField', columns: 20
                    }
                }
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'Number:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'numberField', columns: 5, text: address.number
                    }
                }
                tr {
                    td {
                        label 'City:'
                    }
                    td {
                        textField id: 'cityField', columns: 20, address.city
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Save', actionPerformed: {
                println address
            }
        }

        // Binding of textfield's to address object.
        bean address,
            street: bind { streetField.text },
            number: bind { numberField.text },
            city: bind { cityField.text }
    } 
}
```

Comment: There's one here under the MIT licence https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker